# Android jetpack navigation producing an unexpected error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to use the new navigation graph in android for swapping between fragments. However, I get an error saying :

`This navigation graph is not referenced from any layout files (expected to find it in at least one layout file with a NavHostFragment with app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" attribute).  Navigation resource files must be referenced from a NavHostFragment in a layout in order to be relevant.`

I have seen many poeple with the same error, but everyone seemed to have done something wrong and could correct it. In my case, I am almost 100% sure my code is ok...

Here is my nav_graph.xml :

```
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
            android:name="com.ouimet.budget.MainFragment"
            android:label="fragment_main"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" >
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_expenseFragment"
                app:destination="@id/expenseFragment" />
        </fragment>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/expenseFragment"
            android:name="com.ouimet.budget.ExpenseFragment"
            android:label="fragment_expense"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_expense" />
    </navigation>
```

Along with my MainActivity's resource file activity_main.xml (which references the nav_graph.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And my fragment_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainFragment"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/view_expense_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Entrer une dépense"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As we can see, my nav_graph is referenced.. Also, when I compile and run the code, the transition between the fragments works! Is this a known issue or just me not seeing something?

Thank you for your help!

Alexandre

Comment: I'd try the following: "File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart. Looks like a problem in android studio and is often resolved like that

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer,  I was sure it would work, however the error came back as soon as indexing was done. :(

Comment: Hm weird... in which resource folders are the files located in?

Comment: There is my file layout : https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS0Cc.png

Comment: I am using Android Studio 3.6.2, maybe it is a known issue

Comment: Possibly, if everything is working correctly I'd ignore it for now... maybe it's fixed in a future version.

Comment: Could you share menu file includes your bottom navigation items?

Comment: what do you mean?